# How do I safely get my local git branch back into my fork?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a fork I created on GitHub from a public project. I am working locally on a branch in my fork. While I was working the upstream master changed, so I did reset my forked master and then rebased my branch:

```
git checkout master
git pull upstream master
git reset --hard upstream/master
git push origin master --force

git checkout dovecot-2.3.16
git rebase master
```

Basically, I never work in master or merge to master. Master only follows the upstream.

Now, I want to push my local tree back to my GitHub.com fork, but it fails:

```
$ git push origin
Username for 'https://github.com':
Password for 'https://gerben.wierda@rna.nl@github.com': 
To https://github.com/gctwnl/macports-ports.git
 ! [rejected]                dovecot-2.3.16 -> dovecot-2.3.16 (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/gctwnl/macports-ports.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I don't think I should pull, as I want to get the GitHub.com fork in line with local and not the other way around. But frankly I don't know. How do I get my GitHub.com fork in line with my local `.git`? Simply use `--force`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can force it. Any time you do `git rebase master` to rebase your branch on top of the latest `master` it will cause your local `dovecot-2.3.16` branch to diverge from the remote `origin/dovecot-2.3.16`, which means Git won't allow it to be pushed. It only allows pushes when the local branch is directly descended from the remote one, but rebasing messes that up, and forcing is required.

For safety I recommend you use `push --force-with-lease --force-if-includes`, which will verify that nobody else has updated the branch you're pushing to. A forced push will overwrite other people's changes so it's good to add these safety checks.

To make it easier to type you could create an alias:

```
$ git config --global alias.force-push 'push --force-with-lease --force-if-includes'
$ git force-push
```

---

Try to avoid force pushing unless you know you need to do it. Updating a branch—ideally, a *private* one—after rebasing it is a time where you do need to. But don't get into the habit of just slapping on `--force` any time `git push` fails with some error message you don't understand. (I'm not saying you're doing this. You've shown admirable discretion by posting this question. This is a general warning to anyone reading this.)

On that note, was the force push at the end of this sequence necessary? It should have been doable without `--force`. Next time try a regular push first.

> ```
> git checkout master
> git pull upstream master
> git reset --hard upstream/master
> git push origin master --force
> ```

If it *was* needed then that means that somebody did a force push to the `upstream` remote. Shame on them! People should not be force pushing to public branches. When they do it there's a trickle down effect. Everybody downstream has to start doing `reset --hard`s and `push --force`s to recover from the upstream push, and these are potentially destructive commands. It's a real mess. If you know the person who did the force push upstream, and it wasn't you, I would talk to them and ask them, kindly, to knock it off.

Answer (score 0):

In order to integrate changes in a non disruptive manner is to issue a **merge** instead of a **pull** without **auto merging**.

You should use the commands:

```
git fetch origin/dovecot-2.3.16
git merge origin/dovecot-2.3.16 --no-commit
```

Then you will be able to review changes proposed by the server, and finally commit accepted changes by `git commit` (without any additional comment).